# Is it rude to ask "What have you been doing since you have been here?"

Tags: phrase-meaning, politeness

If I say to my English friends

> What have you been doing since you have been here?

(in fact I want to know how they have been occupied) is it impolite? Why? (tense or verb)

How can I say this better?

Comment: Need more context. This question is perfectly fine in some cases but may come across as too forward in others.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly :)  There are a lot of subtle differences.  As a general rule of thumb, intersperse the sentence with conditionals, use the passive voice and specialize the verb (change "do" to "working on")

[passive vs active](http://www.alumni.org.br/Quiz/Faq/act.html): active adjectives, ending in –ing, express the idea that someone or something causes a certain effect. Passive adjectives, which end in –ed, express that someone or something experiences this effect.

For example

**Impolite**

If said aggressively, this could be interpreted as rude and accusatory (probably not from friends, but can be construed this way)

- What have you been doing since you have been here?
- What do you do?
- What on earth have you been doing?
- What have you been up to?
- What have you done!!?

**Polite**

This should be said quietly with a questioning tone so as not to be confrontational.  Also, small talk is considered polite before getting straight to the question, such as "how was your journey?"

- So, tell me (implies curiosity, not accusation), what have you been working on since we last met?
- Hi, so good to see you, what have you been up to? (balances the accusatory "you" with a nice greeting)
- Hi, good to see you, what have you been up to since we last met?
- Hey, what's up, how are you? (implicit way of saying, what has been going on)
- I can't wait to catch up (very indirect way of saying, what has been going on)
- Have you been travelling? (again, indirect, not asking specifically but an open question that allows them to say exactly what they have been doing)